# Who wrote this programing saying? "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Tags: quotes, code-maintainability

> Always code as if the guy who ends up
>   maintaining your code will be a
>   violent psychopath who knows where you
>   live.

I found this at somebody's blog, and it introduces as Rick Osborne's.  But I google this, and other people says: Martin Golding's, John Woods' and Damian Conway's...  Yes, Damian Conway used this quote in "[Perl Best Practices](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=gJf9tI2mytIC&pg=PT27#v=snippet&q=%22Always%20code%20as%20if%20the%20guy%20who%20ends%20up%20maintaining%20your%20code%20will%20be%20a%20violent%20psychopath%20who%20knows%20where%20you%20live%22&f=false)" (2005) but Damian doesn't mention who wrote it.

Does anybody know who the real author of this aphorism is?

Comment: I can assure you it wasn't me.  I came across it in late 1995 or early 1996 while lurking on a bunch of Perl mailing lists.

Comment: This famous quote was actually wrote by a game programmer called John F. Woods in 1991. Refs: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.c++/rYCO5yn4lXw/oITtSkZOtoUJ) ; [link](http://ruby.zigzo.com/2014/08/01/who-said-that-one-violent-psychopath-quote/). In my opinion this question/topic should be reopened since all questions should be opened for debate and it shouldn't be a reason for closing a topic. Most times it's through debate that we can get a good answer. Except if the topic is not about your favorite color or something like that.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

I thought ChrisW's research was right, and I tried to confirm it by doing the same thing. I found [John Woods' name](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?q=Always+code+as+if+the+guy+who+ends+up+maintaining+your+code+will+be+a+violent+psychopath+who+knows+where+you+live.&sitesearch=groups.google.com&scoring=d&sa=N&start=50) in 1991 in this thread: [Usage of comma operator](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.c++/rYCO5yn4lXw/oITtSkZOtoUJ)

> Bill Mitchell      View profile    More
>   options Sep 26 1991, 1:57 am In
>   article <5...@ksr.com> j...@ksr.com
>   (John F. Woods) writes:
>
> > [...] 
> >     Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a 
> >     violent psychopath who knows where you live.  Code for readability.
>
> Damn right!

So maybe John Woods?

Aug 22, 2014: Link is updated.

Answer (score 12):

Its earliest appearance on Google Groups is unattributed in the sig of a post by Martin Golding in 1994.