# Ruby - retrieve value, validate and assign value in one line

Tags: ruby

```
tc = order.total_cost.to_f rescue nil
msg.totalCost = tc if tc
```

here is `total_cost` retrieved (`order.total_cost.to_f rescue nil`), validated (`if tc`) and assigned (`msg.totalCost = tc`). I wonder whether all the operations could be made in one line without having to retrieve `order.total_cost` twice (assume that retrieval is a heavy time consumer operation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876089/who-wrote-this-programing-saying-always-code-as-if-the-guy-who-ends-up-maintai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it on one line if you must:

```
(tc = order.total_cost.to_f rescue nil) and (msg.totalCost = tc)
```

This is the same logic and may be a bit easier to comprehend:

```
if (tc = order.total_cost.to_f rescue nil) then (msg.totalCost = tc) end
```

If you're willing to use semi-colons, and you know the setter won't raise, this is better:

```
begin; msg.totalCost = order.total_cost.to_f; rescue; end
```

Comment: Can't imagine anyone to be so determined on saving lines to allow this crime against readability :)