# javascript Reg Backwards not works

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a number in a string:
'abc@2003, or something else @2017'
I want to get result [2003, 2007] with match function.

```
let strReg = 'abc@2003, or something else @2017';
let reg = new RegExp(/(?=(@\d+))\1/);  
strReg.match(reg)  //[ '@2003 ', '@2017 ' ]
let reg1 = new RegExp(/(?=@(\d+))\1/)
strReg.match(reg1) //null, but I expect　［2003, 2007］
```

the result mains '\1' match after '?=', ?=()\1 works, ?=@()\1 not.

javascript only supports backwards, how should I do to match '@' but ignore it?

Comment: What's wrong with \d+

Comment: I just focus on "?=@()\1" can not get () match string.　
'abc@2003, or something else @2017' -> [2003, 2007] only an example to show my question.

Comment: I think I know what`s wrong after looking https://msdn.microsoft.com" api,
(?=xxx) is Noncapturing, so '\1' just capture (?=(@\d+)) not (@\d+), and other groups will not be captured too. Noncapturing RegExp start with '?', such as '?=', '?!=', '?<=', '?<!' for save memory. Maybe (?<=@)\d+ can solve my problem, but javascript not support.

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you want an array of the results, so...

```
var s = "abc@2003, or something else @2017 not the 2001 though";
var re = /@(\d+)/g;
var result = [];
var match = re.exec(s);
while (match !== null) {
    result.push(parseInt(match[1]));
    match = re.exec(s);
}

console.log(result);
```

Outputs:

> Array [ 2003, 2017 ]

`match(0)` is the entire match, `match(1)` is the captured group.

Also, see [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432493/1115360)

Inspired by [javascript regex - look behind alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944805/1115360), if you want to do it as almost a one-liner:

```
var re = /(\d+)(?=@)/g; /* write the regex backwards */
var result = [];
s.split('').reverse().join('').match(re).forEach(function (el) { result.push(parseInt(el.split('').reverse().join(''))); });
console.log(result.reverse());
```

Caveat: [Who wrote this programing saying? “Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/876089/1115360)

Comment: Yes, it works, but I want use more simple way or few code to solve the problem. In other worlds, I want use just one RegExp string to get array [2003, 2007], and I don`t want to use while or for. [@2003, @2007] to [2003, 2007] is easy. my point is "the result mains '\1' match after '?=', ?=()\1 works, ?=@()\1 not."

Comment: @Borkes If the string to look in is reversed, you can use a look-behind.

Comment: `let reg1 = new RegExp(/(?=(@(\d+)))\1/)`
 `let reg2 = new RegExp(/(?=(@(\d+)))\2/)`
`strReg.match(reg1) // [@2003, @2007]`
 `strReg.match(reg2) //null`
After look-behind, I expect '\1' get whole group (@(\d+)), '\2' get inner group (\d+), but null

Answer (score 0):

Small change to your code does the job as follows:

```
/@(\d+)/g
```

number followed by `@` will be remembered as you required.

Comment: Why are you using lookahead?

Comment: @Andrew Morton gave a answer, but I want more concise. I want to use Zero width assertion match the place of '@' not '@'