# Output from Get-Content and File Path

Tags: powershell

I have a set of `.txt` files in a folder. For example:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

These contain a date following by a filename. For example, `1.txt` may contain:

```
06/11/2017 randomdocument.txt
06/12/2017 otherdocument.txt
07/11/2017 yadocument.txt
01/02/2017 randomdocument.txt
```

I want to:

- get the line that matches a particular date regex pattern
- write the line, and the path of the file it is in, to a new document.

My code does the first part. I've tried various iterations with no cigar with the second part. Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Code**

```
Set-Location c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORT
$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse
$SearchPattern = "0[5,6]{1}/[0-9]\w{1,2}/2017"

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $line = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Get-Content | Select-String $SearchPattern
  $d = $line | Select-Object file.FullName 
  $d | Add-Content -path c:\users\john.smith\desktop\ohsnap.txt

}
```

---

**Desired Output:**

```
 06/12/2017 randomdocument.txt in c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORT\1.txt
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to choose files that have a `LastWriteTime` property in a specific range?

Comment: Your paragraph is hard to follow, but `gci c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORT -Recurse -pv File| select-string '0[5,6]{1}/[0-9]\w{1,2}/2017' | select Line, @{N='filename';E={$File.FullName}}` ?

Comment: Hello Bill, Yes they are LastWriteTime, but the reports already exist.  So, in other words, I have 3 different .txt files that were run and they contain the LastWriteTime for documents that reside in three separate folders. I am trying to find a way to find all of the line items within each of those those 3 .txt files that meet a specific date criteria (I accomplished this) but then compile them in a new report that gives the path of the line item and which of the three .txt files each line item comes from.  Ex. 06/12/2017 Bobburgers.docx located in c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORTS\1.txt

Comment: TessellatingHeckler.  Thank you. I know.  My paragraph is pretty horrifying; however, I couldn't think of a way to clarify.

Comment: @user7431743 I've edited based on what I think you're asking. Please let me know if it's correct.

Comment: That is absolutely what I am asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minimal changes to the code:

```
Set-Location c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORT

$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse
$SearchPattern = "0[5,6]{1}/[0-9]\w{1,2}/2017"

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $lines =  Get-Content $file | Select-String $SearchPattern
  if($lines){
      foreach($line in $lines){
        "$line`t$($file.FullName)" | Add-Content -path c:\users\john.smith\desktop\ohsnap.txt
      }
  }
}
```

This prints each line on a new line in the new document. If you want all matching lines on a single line, remove the `foreach`:

```
Set-Location c:\users\john.smith\desktop\FORREPORT

$files = Get-ChildItem -recurse
$SearchPattern = "0[5,6]{1}/[0-9]\w{1,2}/2017"

Foreach ($file in $files) {
  $lines =  Get-Content $file | Select-String $SearchPattern
  if($lines){
        "$lines`t$($file.FullName)" | Add-Content -path c:\users\john.smith\desktop\ohsnap.txt
  }
}
```

if will also check see that matched lines were actually found so that you don't get ouput of just `$file.Fullname` with `$lines` is empty.

<sub>PS Your question and code are the best examples I can think of to use [this quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876089/who-wrote-this-programing-saying-always-code-as-if-the-guy-who-ends-up-maintai). heed it! ;-p</sub>

Comment: Yes!  Thank you gmsOulman. This works!  Also, I will heed this.  I am self-taught so there is a lot I have missed in form that I probably would have gotten via a formal training,