# What's a good pattern to calculate a variable only when it is used the first time?

Tags: c++

Not an actual problem but I'm looking for a pattern to improve the following logic:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    std::string message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage(); // This will create a big string with various info
    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
           player->SendMessage(message);
}
```

This code works, but the issue I have is that in most cases there aren't any `gamemasters` players so the message composition will be done for nothing.

I'd like to write something that would only create the message on the first use of that variable, but I can't come up with a good solution here.

EDIT:
To make this question more precise, I'm looking for a solution that's not specific to strings, it could be a type without a function to test if it's initialized.
Also big bonus points if we can keep the call to `GetComplicatedDebugMessage` at the top of the loop, I think a solution involving a wrapper would solve this.

Comment: "*Also big bonus point if we can keep the call to GetComplicatedDebugMessage at the top of the loop*" - why? Then you are right back to initializing the message even if there are no game masters in the list. If it really is so complicated to create the message, why not do so the first time `SendMessage(message)` is actually called?

Comment: The general technique is called "laziness" or "lazy initialization", and is quite common in functional languages.

Comment: Will the message always be the same, or does it have to be recomputed each time the function is called?

Comment: As a note, this task is significantly easier if the object returned by `GetAllPlayers()` provides a means of testing whether it contains any game masters.  That would let you shortcut your logic, so that the function only does anything if there's at least one value where `player->IsGameMaster()` is true.  `auto& players = GetAllPlayers(); if (!players.hasGM()) { return; }`

Comment: @JustinTime It would maybe make more sense to simply create a GetAllGameMasters function instead.

Comment: That's a viable option, too, @Burak.  I was mainly looking at how to quickly check for the presence of one or more game masters before the call to `GetComplicatedDebugMessage()`, while minimising changes to the existing code.

Answer (score 79):

Whereas `std::string` has empty value which might mean "not computed", you might use more generally `std::optional` which handle empty string and non default constructible types:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    std::optional<std::string> message;

    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers()) {
       if (player->IsGameMaster()) {
           if (!message) {
              message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage();
           }
           player->SendMessage(*message);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good. It removes the reliance on "empty == not calculated yet" with absolutely no source code lines overhead.  In fact, sod it, this is what I'd do.

Comment: This answer has the best balance of clarity, efficiency, and extensibility so far.

Comment: Or less pretty. See how that's a matter of opinion?

Comment: And my opinion (we know what those are like) is that there is great value in having { and } vertically aligned with nothing between them (as opposed to having to hunt for the match through all the lines above.

Comment: @ruohola Coding standards are highly subjective and the general guideline around here is to just ignore any compulsion one might have to comment on or change that (when they're following commonly-used coding standards such as those in this answer, at least).

Answer (score 40):

Use [data-oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design); keep two lists of players: game masters and non-game masters (or all players like you have now + a separate vector of pointers to game-masters only).

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    auto players = GetGameMasters(); // Returns ONLY game master players
    if (players.begin() != players.end()) {
        std::string message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage();
        for (Player* player : players) {
            player->SendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is to minimize `if`-statements inside loops.

Optimize for the most common case, not the most generic one; the most common case is that a player is not a game master; so avoid looping over them.

---

P.S. Since you're developing a game, I want to add this link to Mike Acton's [cppcon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc) which you might find interesting.

Comment: I like this a lot.

Comment: Even better would be `if (players.begin() == players.end()) { return; }` and then you can do the actual work without an extra indentation block.

Comment: Also likely to be faster because, presumably, you're likely to have a lot less game masters than regular players, which means the list would be expected to be noticeably smaller.

Comment: More generally, a global variable with the *number* of game masters would probably be useful in many places to simplify code.

Comment: I don't think this is "data-oriented design", but whatever name you give it, "keep two lists" stinks.  You've lost all concept of ordering between master and non-master players, and increased the complexity of iterating the combined set of players in every other place that needs it.

Comment: @BenVoigt It’s fine DOD. Ideally you wouldn’t actually keep two lists, `GetGameMasters` just returns a *view* on the total list with a filter interposed. Pre `ranges` C++ doesn’t make this easy so it’s not a common pattern, but it isn’t hard either.

Comment: There is no need to physically split the players. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: If you build the filtered list on the fly, you don't get the performance benefits that this answer claims.  Indeed filtering on the fly is how I would solve the problem... but the code in the question already does that.  This answer specifically says that two lists are maintained.

Answer (score 37):

Some good ideas here, but I like to keep it a bit more simple:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    std::string message;

    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
    {
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
       {
           if (message.empty())
              message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage();

           player->SendMessage(message);
       }
    }
}
```

Everybody can follow this, and it's cheap as chips… plus it's easy as pie to debug.

Comment: Probably suitable for this case. But in general, what if `message` happens to be empty but still expensive to calculate?

Comment: @sebrockm Then you can introduce a `bool hasMessage` instead. Either way it's pretty trivial logic.

Comment: I do know it's trivial :) but then the entire question is trivial, yet OP asked it. So maybe it's not trivial for them :)

Comment: This is both short and simple. + vote for recognizing when not to use "cool" stuff

Comment: This would perfectly do in this specific example, as well as the "hasMessage" for non-basic types cases, but I'm trying to find shorter pattern I can reuse, probably a wrapper around the message that would avoid the code clutter.

Comment: I mean I kinda get the instinct. But IME for something like this, you're more likely to just make it more complicated than it needs to be. Maybe that's just me though :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's why we have `std::optional`. In this case it fits perfectly.

Comment: @val: Yep, per my comment on Jarod's answer showing this a few hours ago that's what I'd do!

Answer (score 31):

You can use [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) with a lambda to call the function the first time you find a game master like

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    std::once_flag of;
    std::string message;
    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
       {
           std::call_once(of, [&](){ message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage(); });
           player->SendMessage(message);
       }
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot - good use of the C++ Standard Library. Have an upvote!

Comment: I like it too, but this mechanism is specifically designed to handle the problem of concurrency (e.g.: making sure multiple threads only call something once).  As in...it comes with the overhead of an interlock (which could still be very small overhead, but non-zero cost).  Whereas a cheap alternative to call_once that was not designed to handle concurrency would simply be a bool where the once_flag is, and the construct of `if(!hasBeenCalled) { hasBeenCalled=true; fn(); }` <-- That's all you need.  But std::call_once is too convenient to pass up.  Just be aware about what it's for.

Comment: @Wyck Totaly agree.  I just wanted to show it off.  Lightness Races in Orbit's answer is the best for efficiency.

Comment: Nice! That's the kind of answer I was hoping for. It seems it doesn't fit as a generic solution to always reuse because of the lock overhead, but it's very nice to know.

Answer (score 14):

Wrap the message in a mutable lambda:

```
auto makeMessage = [message = std::string()]() mutable -> std::string&
{
    if (message.empty()) {
        message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage();
    }
    return message;
};

for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
   if (player->IsGameMaster())
       player->SendMessage(makeMessage());
```

Comment: I like this one especially, I can make some more generic wrapper out of this easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can extend the approach of using an `std::optional` (as in Jarod41's answer) with lazy evaluation on top. This would also fulfill the requirement to "keep the call to `GetComplicatedDebugMessage` at the top of the loop".

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Lazy : public std::optional<T> {
public:
    Lazy(std::function<T()> f) : fn(f) { }
    T operator*() {
        if (!*this)
            std::optional<T>::operator=(fn());
        return this->value();
    }
private:
    std::function<T()> fn;
};

void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    Lazy<std::string> message(GetComplicatedDebugMessage);
    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
        if (player->IsGameMaster())
            player->SendMessage(*message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the best pattern, but you can delay computation with a lambda:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    std::string message = "";
    auto getDebugMessage = [&message]() -> const std::string& { 
        if (message.empty()) {
            message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage();
        }
        return message;
    };

    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
           player->SendMessage(getDebugMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to keep the definition of `message` above the loop.  If someone's reading the code to analyze what happens in the case where `std::end(GetAllPlayers())==std::begin(GetAllPlayers)()`, you don't want to clutter their mental workspace with irrelevant variables.

If you're willing to give that up, then `static` is your friend:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    for (auto const &player : GetAllPlayers())
        if (player->IsGameMaster())
        {
            //Initialization of a static variable occurs exactly once, even when multithreaded,
            //precisely when the defining line is hit for the first time
            static auto const &message{GetComplicatedDebugMessage()};
            player->SendMessage(message);
        }
}
```

Comment: I imagine the definition was just above the loop to prevent it from getting calculated multiple times (in the absence of another way to do this). If it were me, I'd drop that part from the answer and simply say something like "If `GetComplicatedDebugMessage` is stateless (it's return value doesn't change over multiple calls of the method) and you want to call this only once over all calls of `PrintToGameMasters`, you can use `static`: {code}. If the method is not stateless, you can use one of the solutions suggested in other answers".

Answer (score 2):

This is literally one of the things [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is designed to solve:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    auto message = std::async(
        std::launch::deferred,
        []{return GetComplicatedDebugMessage();}
    );
    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
           player->SendMessage(message.get());
}
```

Invoking `std::async` with [`std::launch::deferred`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) causes the task to be “executed on the calling thread the first time its result is requested”.

Answer (score 1):

This works. As the MIT license would put it:

> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
>   EXPRESS OR IMPLIED

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

struct Player {
    bool isGameMaster;
    int id;
};

int __stdcall IsGameMaster(Player* self) {
    return self->isGameMaster ? 1 : 0;
}

// Could've been "SendMessage"... but Windows.h
void __stdcall SendMessageToPlayer(Player* self, std::string* msg) {
    printf("Player %d says: %s\n", self->id - 1000 + 1, msg->c_str());
}

Player g_players[18];
Player* __stdcall GetAllPlayers(void){
    return &g_players[0];
}

std::string le_message = "hi, I'm a game master";
std::string* __stdcall GetComplicatedMessage(void) {
    puts("GENERATING COMPLICATED MESSAGE. HOGGING CPU FOR 3 DAYS!");
    return &le_message; // to make my assembly life easier
}

__declspec(naked) void PrintToGameMasters(void){
    __asm {
        push ebp;
        mov ebp, esp;
        sub esp, 8;

        call GetAllPlayers;
        mov [ebp-4], eax;

        // this is 'i', the loop iteration counter
        // I chose esi because it is preserved by stdcalls
        xor esi, esi;

        do_loop:

        // Player* player = &g_players[i];
        mov ebx, esi;
        imul ebx, SIZE Player;
        add ebx, [ebp-4]; // ebx = g_players + sizeof(Player) * i, or &g_players[i]

        // if (player->IsGameMaster()) {
        push ebx;
        call IsGameMaster;
        test eax, eax;
        jz no_print;

        // msg = GetComplicatedMessage();
        get_msg_start:
        call GetComplicatedMessage;
        mov [ebp-8], eax;
        jmp short delete_self;
        get_msg_end:

        // player->SendMessage(msg);
        push [ebp-8];
        push ebx;
        call SendMessageToPlayer;

        // }
        no_print:
        inc esi;
        cmp esi, 18;
        jb do_loop;

        mov esp, ebp;
        pop ebp;
        ret;

        delete_self:
        mov ecx, get_msg_start;
        mov eax, get_msg_end;

        sub eax, ecx;
        mov byte ptr [ecx], 0xEB; // jmp short
        mov byte ptr [ecx+1], al; // relative offset
        jmp get_msg_end;
    }
}

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        g_players[i].isGameMaster = (i == 12 || i == 15); // players 13 and 16
        g_players[i].id = i + 1000;
    }

    DWORD oldProtect;
    VirtualProtect(&PrintToGameMasters, 0x1000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);

    PrintToGameMasters();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: code working as intended]

It is **much faster** than the `if (!message) message = GetMessage()` approach, unless you have a CPU with a branch predictor (which you likely do). In that case, it's slower (or maybe equally fast, but not faster), uglier, less portable, and will likely [get you killed by a psychopath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876089/who-wrote-this-programing-saying-always-code-as-if-the-guy-who-ends-up-maintai).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom local type with a conversion operator:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    struct {
        operator std::string const &(void)
        {
            static auto const real_value{GetComplicatedDebugMessage()};
            return real_value;
        }
    } message;
    for (auto const &player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster())
           player->SendMessage(message);
}
```

Of course, this assumes that `GetComplicatedDebugMessage` is in fact stateless.  Otherwise, you'll need to resort to capturing a lambda, or similar tricks described in the other answers here.

Comment: The *idea* is good but your answer contains several errors: Your code will recompute the value every time, it won’t cache it. You probably forgot a `static` in front of the local `real_value` variable. The code, as it stands, also causes UB because the lifetime extension for `const&` won’t extend beyond `return` statements (i.e. it can’t leave the scope). Just remove the reference on the local variable.

Comment: Yes; your corrections are precisely what I meant.  I've corrected the answer now.

Answer (score -1):

*Really hope this helps*

Try maybe implementing this logic:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool GameMaster,first_time,used_before;

    GameMaster = true;
    first_time = false;
    used_before = false;

    GameMaster = first_time;
    first_time = used_before;


    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

        if(GameMaster==used_before) {
            cout<<"    First Time";
            GameMaster = true;
        }

        if(GameMaster!=used_before) {
            cout<<"    Old News";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With Response:

```
  First Time    Old News    Old News    Old News    Old News    Old News
```

Comment: FWIW `i = i + 1` can be replaced by `++i`, `if(GameMaster!=used_before)` can be replaced by `else`, You can also get rid of two of the three `bool`'s as you only need one flag to know if one thing has been done.

Comment: I didn't say im expert, I was trying to pass variable values, without affecting the previous one. I used this logic before for button polling and it did the job, I didn't consider that bc he only needs to read the change once, 3 variables are overkill. Looks like it could have been done easier, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Dunno, seems too wordy. Also fix your indentation!!

Answer (score -1):

`static` variables are initialized on first time through.  So:

```
void PrintToGameMasters()
{
    for (Player* player : GetAllPlayers())
       if (player->IsGameMaster()) {
           static std::string message = GetComplicatedDebugMessage(); // This will create a big string with various info
           player->SendMessage(message);
       }
}
```

This is, of course, assuming that calculating the value once at most (rather than once per call at most) is a valid way of proceeding.  It's not clear from how you phrased your task whether this is the case.